# Reading a dicom file in C

Tags: c, dicom

How do I read a dicom file, with different tags, in C?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662591/what-c-library-can-i-use-to-read-pixels-from-dicom-images) for starters (yes, I know it's asking about C++).

Answer (score 2):

MergeCOM-3 is one of the best and widely used DICOM Library.

Yes it is paid.But you can use trial version for learning purpose.

Sample and documentation are of very good quality.

http://www.mergecom3.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can find a library [here](http://www.rtstudents.com/pacs/free-dicom-viewers.htm) or [here](http://www.idoimaging.com/cgi-sys/cgiwrap/acrabb/imaging/programs.pl?order=program.percentile&).

Comment: If you search on idoimaging.com, one of the links, you can bring up about eight C DICOM libraries.